# Ember Computed Property using JS apply()

Tags: ember.js

I would like to make the following code work if at all possible.  The goal is to have a computed property that depends on a list of strings by using Javascripts "apply" method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

```
App.View = Em.View.extend
  myProps: ['content.prop1', 'content.prop2']
  myComputed : (->
    return "super valuable things"
  ).property.apply(@get("myCompted"), @get("myProps"))
```

So far...no luck.  It just seems to reject my most earnest desire to make this work.

Any help would be supremely appreciated!
Steve

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the `apply` function and I'm not sure why you think you need to do that. The property function only wants an argument of the property it depends upon. In this case it is `'myProps'`. You do not need to `get` that property either, Ember will work it all our for you.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/nv7y5/13/) and you'll see what I mean. You can do all your manipulation of the array inside the `myComputed` property and the array will have been made available for you already.

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    myProps: ['123', '456'],
    myComputed : function () {
        return this.get('myProps');
    }.property('myProps')
});
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the goal.  myProps is an array of OTHER properties that I wish to depend on.  Consider this fiddle:

Comment: You forgot to include the link to the fiddle. :)

Comment: Sorry I had a massive early morning brainfart and decided to not actually link to anything or finish my thought.  What I want to do is construct an array of strings that are the names of properties i wish to depend on.  Then pass that array of strings to .property and have it recompute whenever any of those props change.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Deif/nv7y5/13/ here is a fiddle that shows some of my tinkering.  The goal here would be to simply define a list of strings ["prop1", "prop2"] and then pass that list as a single argument to myComputed and have myComputed update any time prop1 or prop2 was updated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nv7y5/18/ apologies too many ideas floating around.  This fiddle shows an implementation wherein the user of the mixin may decide which properties are used in calculating their styleString from a finite list of possible props (prop1 - prop5).  This method allows me as the mixin author to define all possible choices for computed property dependence while allowing the user to choose which properties they desire to depend on.

Comment: Hmm I've had a play around and I have no idea how to get a dynamic array of properties to be observed.